# is there any alternative way to provide input to readline apart from console?

Tags: java, command-line, system.in

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));          
 System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
 String name = reader.readLine();
```

can i provide input from java code instead of console ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file to do that.
Using the same **BufferedReader** and read the complete input values from the file.

And if not that either, you can't use a simple console project and ask for a graphical input system.
You can rather add Java Swing to your project and use a graphically oriented form with text fields for it input.

Comment: how do i ask for graphical input and how do i use graphically oriented form for input ?

Comment: You can look for a tutorial for Jawa Swing.
You won't need to re-create your existing project.

All you will have to do is add a Java Swing module to your project.
You can find good tutorials easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOptionPane#showInputDialog` to get the input with some graphical dialogs from user instead of console. It is not the ideal way for a professional program but it is so easier for now to get started with swing `JFrame`, `JTextField`, `JComboBox` etc. and diving into the world of handling actions of `JButton` or so.

Example:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name: ");
```

More detailed `JOptionPane#showInputDialog` overloads are available and if you want to create more elegant input dialogs. A quick tutorial can be found [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showinputdialog-examples).